# iPhone 6s iOS9 not using my web app icon in a sub-directory/folder

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I store all of my web app icons and favicons in a sub-directory to keep organised:

`http://example.com/Images/favicons/example-web-app-icon.png`

However when I use this meta data in my markup (generated by NPM package `favicons`):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
```

My iPhone 6s with iOS 9 does not pick up my icon and instead uses a screenshot of the page.

Is there a size my markup is missing or what? I'd rather not put any of the icons in the root directory.

Comment: If your url is `http://example.com/Images/example-web-app-icon.png`, why did you add `.../favicons/...` in your links? Can you add the real url of your webapp to help you to debug?

Comment: Sorry it should be `/Images/favicons` my example URL was just not correct. I can't link directly to the web app as it is on my local machine in a corporate environment. :(

Comment: Try to add the default one (without any sizes) `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60@2x.png" />`

Comment: What is the URL of the page that you try to add to your iPhone's 'Home page'